# Make Salesforce dependent picklist work in a .NET web interface

Tags: .net, api, salesforce

Salesforce allows the use of dependent picklist as described here: http://ap1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_defining_field_dependencies.htm

We have a web interface coded in .NET communicating via API with Salesforce.

Does anyone have experience making dependent picklist fields from Salesforce work in a .NET web interface?

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks!
Izumi.